# Prove this lemma $A\cup B=\left(A-B\right)\cup B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have to prove two directions: $A\cup B\subseteq\left(A-B\right)\cup B$ and $A\cup B\supseteq\left(A-B\right)\cup B$

I'm quite confident that this direction is correct: $\left(\supseteq\right)$ Let $x\ \in\left(A-B\right)\cup B.$ Thus, $x\ \in A-B\ or\ x\ \in B.$ Thus, $x\ \in A\ |x\ \notin B$ or $x\ \in B$. It follows that $x\ \in A$ or $x\ \in B$ because $A-B\ \subseteq A$. Thus, $x\ \in A\ \cup B$. QED.

However, this direction is so confusing: $\left(\subseteq\right)$ Let $x\ \in A\ \cup B$. Thus, $x\ \in A$ or $ x\ \in B$.

What should be the next analysis? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your next steps should be:

$$x\in A \lor x\in B$$

$$(x\in A, x\not\in B \lor x\in A, x\in B) \lor x\in B$$

$$x\in A, x\not\in B \lor (x\in A, x\in B \lor x\in B)$$

$$x\in A, x\not\in B \lor x\in B$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in B$, then it is also in $(A-B)\cup B$. If it is not in $B$, it is in $A$ and thus in $A-B$.